# Basic HTML operations in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am working with HTML in Emacs and I am looking for ways to make basics operations as:

- convert list of string to HTML-list

  ```
  one
  two
  three
  ```

  to

  ```
  <ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
  </ul>
  ```
- add class to list of elements

  ```
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  ```

  to

  ```
  <a class="one"></a>
  <a class="one"></a>
  <a class="one"></a>
  ```

Is there any extensions which can helps me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with a macro:

- Move to the first line, and type `C-x (`
- Type the `<li>`, move to the end `</li>`, and move to the next line
- End and repeat the macro on the remaining lines with `C-x e e e e e`...

This can easily be generalized to add classes to your `<a>` tags, and many other things.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [zencoding](https://github.com/rooney/zencoding) , it's pretty useful. [Here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2r8JfJJgy8) a youtube video showing it with [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/), showing some functionality like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to list of elements using command M-x replace-string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Emacs Lisp function which performs the first task (operates on selected text):

```
(defun my-make-list (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (insert "<ul>\n")
  (mapcar '(lambda (line) (insert (concat " <li>" line "</li>\n")))
          (split-string (buffer-substring start end) "\n"))
  (insert "</ul>")
  (delete-region start end))
```

In the second case I would just use search/replace.